# Windows Live Writer Automation

Tags: c#, windows-live-writer

I would like to be able to open Windows Live Writer from my (C#) application and have the beginnings of a blog post filled out.

This should be very simple. Windows Live Writer defines an [Application API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa738851.aspx) that exposes a COM interface called [WindowsLiveWriterApplicationLib](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa738851.aspx). According to blog posts such as [this](http://scottisafooldev.wordpress.com/2008/03/18/writing-an-application-that-opens-windows-live-writer/), after you add a new reference to the typelib (usually located here: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Writer\WindowsLiveWriter.Application.tlb), you should be able to write code like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    var wlw = new WindowsLiveWriterApplicationLib.WindowsLiveWriterApplicationClass();
    wlw.BlogThisHtml("test","test");

}
```

...except it isn't working. Doesn't event compile. Instead I get errors like this:

```
Error   1   The type 'WindowsLiveWriterApplicationLib.WindowsLiveWriterApplicationClass' has no constructors defined    

Error   2   Interop type 'WindowsLiveWriterApplicationLib.WindowsLiveWriterApplicationClass' cannot be embedded. Use the applicable interface instead.  

Error   3   'WindowsLiveWriterApplicationLib.WindowsLiveWriterApplicationClass' does not contain a definition for 'BlogThisHtml' and no extension method 'BlogThisHtml' accepting a first argument of type 'WindowsLiveWriterApplicationLib.WindowsLiveWriterApplicationClass' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

It claims the class can't be embedded, has no constructors, and does not contain the method I am calling. (when it clearly does in Object Explorer.)

What obvious thing am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Managed to get it working.

I wound up having to register WindowsLiveWriter.Application.dll using RegSvr32.exe. After that it started working.

Here is working code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    WindowsLiveWriterApplication wlw = new WindowsLiveWriterApplication();
    ((IWindowsLiveWriterApplication2)wlw).BlogThisHtml("test", "testhtml");

}
```

Comment: I'd just like to say that is now 3 and a half years later and I just found this post by googling for the same question. I found it helpful (it answered the question I had). So I try to upvote it and realize that both the question AND the answer are by me! Hilarious!